# Shared Preferences String List returning null

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this function to save the List whenever I add a new item to the list :

```
void saveList() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setStringList('list', global.contactList);
  }
```

and load it in  main.dart using :

```
void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  loadData();
  runApp(MyApp());

  }
loadData()async{
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  global.number = await prefs.getString('number');
  global.contact = await prefs.getString('contact');
  global.contactList = await prefs.getStringList('list');
}
```

but I get null when loading the list although I have a valid list with data and no errors when saving

Comment: How do you determine that it is null? You are calling loadData without awaiting it, so this might be an issue.

Comment: I added await, this is not the issue.@puelo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work, the solution is to use `jsonEncode` and `jsonDecode` to save a String instead of a list، like this:

```
  void saveList() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     await prefs.setString('list', jsonEncode(global.contactList));
  }
```

and to load:

```
Future getList()async{
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  global.contactList = await jsonDecode(prefs.getString('list'));
  return global.contactList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you update ui after gotten data?
First, your list will equal to null and then it will get data from SharedPreference.

Use FutureBuilder widget to show data from SharedPrefernce

```
Future getList()async{
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 
  global.contactList = await prefs.getStringList('list');
return global.contactList;
}
```

```
return FutureBuilder(
    future: getList()// here future function which return data from sharedPreference,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return YourFinalWidget();
      }
else if (snapshot.hasError) {         
                return Center(child:Text("${snapshot.error}"));
              }
      return CircularProgressIndicator(); // or some other widget
    },
  );
```

Comment: The Circular Progress bar is just rotating endlessly @islam akhrarov

Comment: retry edited code and in your ui u will see error

Comment: No, I didn't get any errors. seems like the data is not loading at all @islam akhrarov